# Does BitBucket allow fork to be created from existing forks?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-branch

I have a repository. From this main repo, I have created 3 forks for X, Y and Z websites. Now, I want to keep the Z fork as the base for another website. In this regard, I think I need to create a fork of the Z repo fork and clone the same in my local machine.

- Is my approach correct?
- Why can't I find the option to create a fork
  from the Z repo?

> ```
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVyWv.png
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU3OQ.png
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself and tested the same.

1. Yes, the approach is correct
2. The option to create a fork was not visible since it was disabled in the "Repositories Settings" page. This page is accessed via the "Settings" link. The forking parameter was set to "No forks". I changed it to "Allow only private forks".